# how to optimise my code to run on a Windows 2012 Server

Tags: r

My code is running very slowly on my laptop and i have access to a windows 2012 server x64 with 256Gb ram.

I have the server set up running R and have this code working but 48 hours = 25%

From what i have learnt its due to only using one core.

Currently I'm exploring foreach loop but getting nowhere slowly

```
library("sp")
library("rgeos")
library("geosphere")
library("gdistance")

# Data
dna <- data.frame(cbind(rnorm(400) * 2 + 13, rnorm(400) + 48))
dna$ID <- seq.int(nrow(dna))

match <- data.frame(cbind(rnorm(4000) * 2 + 13, rnorm(4000) + 48))
match$ID <- seq.int(nrow(match))

##Set row id 
RID2 <- 1

#create output table 
tablelength <- print (nrow(dna))

match1 = data.frame( UPRN=rep(0, tablelength), Long=rep(0,tablelength), Lats=rep(0,tablelength),   MatchID=rep(0,tablelength) , Longm=rep(0,tablelength), Latsm=rep(0,tablelength), distance=rep(0,tablelength))

#start loop
for(RID2 in dna[,3]) {

  #Set UPRN and Exchange Name
  Name <- paste(dna[RID2,3])

  set1 <- data.frame(dna[RID2,1:2])
  set2 <- data.frame(match[,1:2])

  set1sp <- SpatialPoints(set2)
  set2sp <- SpatialPoints(set1)

  set1$ID <- apply(gDistance(set1sp, set2sp, byid=TRUE), 1, which.min)
  ID <- paste(apply(gDistance(set1sp, set2sp, byid=TRUE), 1, which.min))

  #insert Row
  match1[RID2, ] = c(Name, set1[,1], set1[,2], paste(match[ID,3]), set2[ID,1], set2[ID,2],     distVincentyEllipsoid(c(set1[,1], set1[,2]), c(set2[ID,1], set2[ID,2]), a=6378137, b=6356752.3142, f=1/298.257223563))

  remove(set1,set2,set1sp,set2sp)
}
```

The output is what i am looking for but ideally with a sub 1 day runtime (currently at 8)

Comment: Is *this* code the code that runs for `48*4` hours? If so, I request (strongly suggest) that you reduce the size and look for a scaled improvement.

Comment: @r2evans This is the code but with a sample data set. What do you mean by reduce the size?

Comment: How long does this code take to run? I don't really have 8 days to throw at this ;-) (I figured it was a replacement dataset.)

Comment: @r2evans Ahh sorry yes, This only took
      user  system elapsed 
   8.27    0.00    8.37 
to run so around 8 seconds.

Comment: Some things might be removed, not sure if they are bottlenecks: `set2` and `set2sp` do not change each pass in the loop. Also, never ever ever ever add a row each pass through a loop, it performs really poorly in the end. Lastly, you calculate `apply(gDistance(...))` twice, why?

Comment: Do you intentionally swap 1 and 2 when making `set1sp` and `set2sp`?

Comment: Another, you are using `paste` in a way that converts an integer into a character, but then use that char to index on defaulted row names. This is highly non-standard, seems to have no purpose, and could easily get you in trouble.

Comment: Note that questions about how to improve working code are generally considered too broad to be on-topic here unless they focus on a very specific and narrow problem (and that code *must* have a *specific* problem; "it's too slow" doesn't count). Our sister site [codereview.se] is more welcoming to such questions, within their own rules; see [A Guide To Code Review For Stack Overflow Users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/155649).

Comment: be careful: seems to me that you are mixing two different distance metrics (one cartesian and one over lat/long).

Comment: @r2evans A lot of the inefficiency is due to my own lack of understanding around using R let alone using it efficiently. i swapped them round as when testing it worked so i didn't think much more of it. i calculated apply(gdistance twice to get the answer out into 2 different locations. i believe that was a legacy thing and thinking about it now it was stupid. I was was trying to get the distance and rowid out but couldn't figure out how.

I now have code working that ran over night and did everything. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for the heads up. I will check out code Review. I think i picked here due tio wanting to leverage the multicore power of the server to speed the code up more but clearly didnt do a god job of articuling this. (it was late and been a hell of a week)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, and cuts calculation time (on your sample data) in half on my machine..

```
set.seed(123)
# Data
dna <- data.frame(cbind(rnorm(400) * 2 + 13, rnorm(400) + 48))
dna$ID <- seq.int(nrow(dna))

match <- data.frame(cbind(rnorm(4000) * 2 + 13, rnorm(4000) + 48))
match$ID <- seq.int(nrow(match))

###
library( sf )
library( data.table )
dna.sf <- st_as_sf( x = dna, 
                    coords = c( "X1", "X2"), 
                    crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84" )

match.sf <- st_as_sf( x = match, 
                      coords = c( "X1", "X2"), 
                      crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84" )

#create data.tables
setDT(dna)
setDT(match)
#add suffixes to identify columns later (after join)
setnames(dna, names(dna), paste0(names(dna),".dna"))
setnames(match, names(match), paste0(names(match),".match"))

#create distance matrix
m <- round( st_distance( dna.sf, match.sf ), digits = 0 )
colnames( m ) <- match.sf$ID
rownames( m ) <- dna.sf$ID
#get colname of min to nearest (remember, colname = match-ID ;-) )
dna$nearest <- apply( m, 1, which.min )
#get the min distance
dna$dist <- apply( m, 1, min )
#now left-join to get the coordinates of match, use data.table for speed
library( data.table )
result <- match[dna, on = c("ID.match==nearest") ]
```

The results seem to be the same as when using your 'old' method, but calculation time is roughly cut in half (7.5 -> 4 secs)

Answer (score 0):

You can already get a good speed boost by simply optimizing the code and removing redundant parts. For example, this is more or less twice as fast on the test data, and is easily parallelizable.

```
library("sp")
library("rgeos")
library("geosphere")
library("gdistance")

# Data
dna <- data.frame(cbind(rnorm(400) * 2 + 13, rnorm(400) + 48))
dna$ID <- seq.int(nrow(dna))

match <- data.frame(cbind(rnorm(40000) * 2 + 13, rnorm(40000) + 48))
match$ID <- seq.int(nrow(match))

##Set row id 
RID2 <- 1

#create output table 
tablelength <- nrow(dna)
matchlist <- list()
set2 <- match[,1:2]
set1sp <- SpatialPoints(set2)
for(RID2 in dna[,3]) {
  set1 <- dna[RID2,1:2]
  set2sp <- SpatialPoints(set1)
  ID <- which.min(gDistance(set1sp, set2sp, byid=TRUE))
  #insert Row
  matchlist[[RID2]] = data.frame(UPRN = dna[RID2,3], 
                                 Long = set1[,1], 
                                 Lats = set1[,2], 
                                 matchid = match[ID,3], 
                                 Longm = set2[ID,1],
                                 Latsm = set2[ID,1], 
                                 distance = distVincentyEllipsoid(set1, set2[ID,],
                                                                  a=6378137, b=6356752.3142, f=1/298.257223563))
}
match1 <- data.table::rbindlist(matchlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks you all for your input i will be reading the different styles to further my R learning's.

I have used a solution posted from the reddit thread i also made at the same time.

```
require(foreach)
require(doParallel)

cl <- makeCluster(4)
registerDoParallel(cl)
temp <- foreach(I = 1:nrow(dna),.combine = "c", .packages = c("rgeos","sp"))     %dopar% {
    return(c(which.min(
        gDistance(
        SpatialPoints(data.frame(dna[I,1:2]))
        , SpatialPoints(data.frame(match[,1:2]))
        , byid=TRUE
        ))))
}
```

https://old.reddit.com/r/rstats/comments/aebamb/how_do_i_use_all_the_cores_on_a_server_to_match/

Again thank you for the help :-D